# convert string time to int

Tags: go

I want to convert a string time `"2019-06-20 13:30:31"` to int `20190620`, I tried with below codes, but I got `10190101` instead, what's wrong with my trial?

```golang
func (u *Util) ConvertStringTimeToInt(stringTime string) (intTime int64) {
    timeLayout := "2019-01-01 01:01:01"
    timeOutput := "20190101"
    tmp, _ := time.Parse(timeLayout, stringTime)
    out := tmp.Format(timeOutput)
    outInt, _ := strconv.ParseInt(out, 10, 64)
    return outInt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time format uses specific values to denote time/date elements. 2006 is year, 01 is month, etc. So to parse that date, your layout must be:

```
timeLayout:="2006-01-02 15:04:05"
```

Once you parse it, there is an easier way of doing what you need:

```
outInt:=t.Year()*10000+int(t.Month())*100+t.Day()
```

Or, use similar layout to convert to string, and then to int.